# Preserve page position on fullscreen exit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using slider jQuery plugin, need to return to screen position before enter fullscreen when exit fullscreen.

In each listener event.target is slider instance:

```
slider.ev.on('rsEnterFullscreen', function() {
    // enter fullscreen mode 
});
slider.ev.on('rsExitFullscreen', function() {
    // exit fullscreen mode 
});
```

Comment: We have no idea what slider you are using, or what your html looks like. Provide more code detail and slider info along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var g_position;
slider.ev.on('rsEnterFullscreen', function() {
    g_position = $(window).scrollTop()
});
slider.ev.on('rsExitFullscreen', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(g_position); 
});
```